# Entity Framework vs. ADO.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ado.net

In ASP.NET MVC3 projects, is it faster, more secure, to use Entity Framework (with the repository pattern) or to use ADO.NET with `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`?

Comment: This question is pretty ambiguous and would be better suited for programmers.stackexchange.com as there is no code specific answer.

Comment: @ErikPhilips - Do you use EF?

Comment: **Yes** - it is faster for you as the programmer to use EF - it hides quite a few implementation details from you, so there's less to learn, less to master. And **yes** - using raw ADO.NET will be faster in terms of runtime performance, since EF is really a layer on top of ADO.NET - and every additional layer does cost some runtime performance. However: as long as the runtime performance of Entity Framework is **good enough** for your application - there's really no point in wasting all your development time to squeeze out more runtime performance by using raw ADO.NET - EF is **good enough**!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very general question but some thoughts.

**Performance:**

Plain SqlCommand and DataReader will be significantly faster when it comes to performance as long as all the developers has a clue. With .net 4.5 and EF 5 it seems like EF will get a nice performance boost but plain sql will always be faster.

See here for some numbers: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/14/sneak-preview-entity-framework-5-0-performance-improvements.aspx

Plain ADO.NET also supports the async patter which might be very important in some scenarios. EF doesn't. Atleast not for EF 4.

**Security**

Plain SQL might be as safe as EF as long as you use paramaterized queries. EF will do this automatically for you to protect you from SQL injection. Because EF always gives you this I would consider it safer but with a slight margin.

**Testability**

I have found this to be a big win when it comes to EF. Instead of fooling around with mocking I run fast intergration tests against my controllers using SqlCe4. It's very easy to do this as long as you use EF.

**Summary**

I find EF very capable and the API is pleasant to work with. If you are doing performance intensive things you will have to drop into raw SqlDataReader and SqlBulkCopy from time to time but mixing them is not a problem. I like to use EF where I can live with the performance loss because I'm more productive. Where I feel the hit is to big I will use plain Sql.

Comment: Good post, but the performance external like is really not helpful.  I mean a 23 times longer on a 4ms query is 120ms.  That is not really noticeable.  And even more meaningless is the fact that the speed difference is not due to SQL performance, but more often than not SQL generation.  So a query that normally take 4 seconds to run is not going to be 23 times longer (92 seconds).  This is by no means a comment on your post, but the complexity if doing correct data gathering (of which microsoft obviously did not do).

Comment: The problem is when you are thinking about servers. Placing 23x more cpu (or 4x with EF5) is a pretty significant scalability issue(In some cases). My point really is: use EF where the slower perf won't be a problem. But be ready to measure it and drop to ADO.NET if needed.

Answer (score 2):

I use both depending on the needs of a project.  Here is my take:

*better (very ambiguous)*

In this instance I would define better as a product/feature that provide me with a way to create a solution with less code to write, less run-time bugs to detect, and more features.

In this aspect, Entity Framework (EF) gives me Insert/Update/Delete statements, strongly-typed models, and a way to create dynamic strongly-typed sql statements.

*faster*

EF is slower and depending on your experience/knowledge, it can be hundreds of times slower.  With the correct knowledge of how to use EF the speed difference in negligible.

*security*

Neither ADO nor EF provide any means of security (to my knowledge).  Security typically is controlled at the presentation (IIS, Winforms, etc) and/or on SQL server.

The only major limitation I've found using EF (and maybe I haven't found the solution) is the inability for it strongly-type update records like:

```
UPDATE [sometable]
SET [column1] = 'new value'
WHERE [column2] = 'shared ID value'
```

Where, depending on the reuse of this method, I either use SqlCommand or write a Stored Procedure.

**Update from 1st Comment**

In regards to Stored Procedures, Entity Framework (EF) is very mature at this point, and not only can Store Procedures be called from EF, but each model's data methods (Select, Insert, Update, Delete) can be mapped to a Stored Procedure.  I have not personally done this, but it's definitely part of the framework.

As for calling a Stored Procedure from a security point of view, the Stored Procedures security is stored on the SQL server.  If it can't be called from EF then it wouldn't be able to be called from a SqlCommand either.

Comment: I will remove better from the question, you are correct in that it is very ambiguous. Speed was a main concern, so I am happy to hear you say that there isn't much difference there. As for security, it was my understanding that EF will not work with stored procedures hence the issue of security being brought up. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Update per your comment on Stored Procedures.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you go for Entity framework, It will save you some dev time as it will generate most of the code for you. But in the case of ADO.NET with SQlConnection and SQLCommand, you need to write your own methods for create/update/delete in your data access layer.

I seriously think using ADO.NET stored proc gives some performance advantage as the execution plan is stored in the server.

> When a SQL statement is executed, the database has to generate an
>   execution plan for it. If that SQL statement is run repeatedly, each
>   time it is executed the database might have to regenerate the query's
>   execution plan. In these cases where SQL is run frequently, moving the
>   SQL to a stored procedure can offer greater performance (not to
>   mention greater security). The first time a stored procedure is
>   executed, the database generates a query execution plan, stores that
>   plan in the procedure cache, and then executes the stored procedure.
>   On subsequent calls of the stored procedure, the database engine only
>   has to grab the query plan from the procedure cache and rerun the
>   stored procedure. Thus, it skips the step of devising the query plan
>   on subsequent calls

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163799.aspx

Comment: There is a big performance difference between EF and pure ADO.NET. EF is slower in execution time but it's a lot faster in development time.

Comment: @WouterdeKort : Agreed. I updated my answer to include your point.